# hyperref: pdftitle and wrong character encoding

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using non ASCII characters in author names and titles within hyperref pdfinfo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/using-non-ascii-characters-in-author-names-and-titles-within-hyperref-pdfinfo)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,pdftitle=Some title żźćąęśćół]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

How can I make pdftitle correctly generated?
I'm getting (checked with Adobe Reader X):
`Sometitle»¹¢¡¦±¢ó`
There are no spaces and there are fizzled Polish diacritics. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The spaces are kept if you put the title in braces. If you compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex` the Polish diacritics work. I don't how to make it work with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\hypersetup` to set up strings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=Some title żźćąęśćół}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

This is recommended at the hyperref manual.

Comment: It seems that the option `unicode` works for the strings set up in `\hypersetup`, but *not* for the strings set up in options.  This is probably the reason why the method you recommend works.

Comment: @Boris: The optional argument of `\usepackage` is ready by the LaTeX kernel, so hyperref cannot change scanning of the argument. The argument of `\hypersetup` will be read under control of hyperref. hyperref may e.g. change encoding before reading the argument.

Comment: @schweinebacke yes, this is what I meant

Comment: so is there anyway to predefine title, authors in a separated file, i.e. `options.tex`, and then call them in a `setup.tex` file where `\hypersetup` is put?