# Hyperref pdftitle manages line breaks in a strange way

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I use `XeLaTeX` with `fontspec`, `polyglossia`, `biblatex` and `hyperref` packages (etc.) to typeset my documents as `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}` . The `hyperref` package is just awesome, however, I have found a really annoying bug.

I want the `pdftitle` to use a combination of some static text and a previously defined variable `\thetitle`. So far so good. The problem arises when this variable contains line breaks (`\\`). `hyperref` seems to simply omit them automatically but I want to be able to control this manually.

To get rid of the line breaks I use this macro `\replacelinebreaks{}{}`:

```
% A macro to remove line breaks from any text #1 and replace them 
% with #2 (can be void). E.g.: \replacelinebreaks{\thetitle}{\ }. 
\newcommand{\replacelinebreaks}[2]{%
    \begingroup\def\\{#2}#1\endgroup}
```

(The credit for it goes mostly to [Easy way to remove formatting (e.g. linebreaks)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35884/easy-way-to-remove-formatting-e-g-linebreaks).) This macro works fine everywhere throughout the document - except in `\hypersetup{pdftitle= ...}`.

What am I missing here? There are quite a lot of very similar questions on this site, but none seems to solve my particular problem:

- [Using non ASCII characters in author names and titles within hyperref pdfinfo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/using-non-ascii-characters-in-author-names-and-titles-within-hyperref-pdfinfo), but I already use `\hypersetup`

  1. I also tried creating a new variable without line breaks, but the error just seems to propagate throughout.
  2. Using a code for special characters (e.g. `\040` should be a space) does not produce any difference.
- [hyperref: pdftitle and wrong character encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/hyperref-pdftitle-and-wrong-character-encoding), same argument.
- [pdfinfo doesn't appear to be working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48067/pdfinfo-doesnt-appear-to-be-working), same argument again.
- [hyperref : break long lines in pdftitle and other fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285954/hyperref-break-long-lines-in-pdftitle-and-other-fields). `\textLF` and `\textCR` do not solve my problem. Foxit Reader does not recognize those characters while Adobe Acrobat and Acrobat Reader display only the first line. My issue lies with `hyperref`.
- [Non-ascii characters are not displayed in hyperref's pdftitle: bug in the 'unicode' option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79897/non-ascii-characters-are-not-displayed-in-hyperrefs-pdftitle-bug-in-the-unico). In my case, `\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}` does not change anything.
- [Make hyperref take pdfinfo from \title and \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/make-hyperref-take-pdfinfo-from-title-and-author). Admittedly, if I use `\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}` the `\hypersetup` is obsolete and the line breaks are automatically converted to space (for pdftitle) and to comma (for pdfauthor). However, as noted before, I want a combination of static text and `\thetitle`, so `\hypersetup` is unavoidable.

  1. The `\@title` approach would not help as it is already used to define `\thetitle` in the first place.

Here is my MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\replacelinebreaks}[2]{\begingroup\def\\{#2}#1\endgroup}

\def\thetitle{Type the\\Minimum Working Example\\Title Here\\}      
\def\firstauthor{Abra}      % Only the first author 
\def\theauthor{\firstauthor %  Add all other authors (no spaces! Use "\\" and "%")
\\Ca%                   
\\Dabra%
} 

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle    = MWE No.1 \space -- \replacelinebreaks{\thetitle}{\ },
    pdfauthor   = \replacelinebreaks{\theauthor}{; },
}

\begin{center}
    {\Huge\thetitle}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It results in:

[image]

Please help me understand and correct this behaviour, so I could either use my `\replacelinebreaks` macro or achieve my goal in some other way. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you provide some code for tests?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: MWE is now provided. I am running some tests for your proposed solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always can redefine the way hyperref handles such tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\myvar{abc\\cde}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\{XXX}}
\hypersetup{pdftitle= abc\\ cde\myvar}

\begin{document}
blub

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can define your variable so that it uses in sensible places `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\myvar{abc\texorpdfstring{\\}{XXX}cde}

\hypersetup{pdftitle= abcXXXcde\myvar}

\begin{document}
\myvar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do these commands affect only `hyperref` or the whole document? In my case, the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\{ }}`works fine for `\thetitle`, but not for `\theauthor`, where line breaks have to be replaced not with space, but with "`; `". It seems that I cannot have two such exceptions at once ...

Comment: You can add another set: `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\{YYY}}\hypersetup{pdfauthor= abc\\ cde\myvar}` and later set the definition to someelse, e.g. for the bookmarks.