# pdf properties with french accents

Tags: hyperref, pdf, accents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using non ASCII characters in author names and titles within hyperref pdfinfo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/using-non-ascii-characters-in-author-names-and-titles-within-hyperref-pdfinfo)

I can write the accents in the properties of a PDF document using macros, like `\'e` when i want the `é` in "mathématiques"

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[pdfsubject={Math\'ematiques}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
toto
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to write directly accents without using macros like `\'e`?

```
\usepackage[pdfsubject={Mathématiques}]{hyperref}
```

Google guided me to the package `ucs` and the macro `PrerenderUnicode` but i can't find the good way to use that.

Edit: I found the error i made : The character encoding of my document was iso-8859, i change it to utf8 and all is working.

Comment: Well, either `\usepackage[pdfsubject={Mathématiques}]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage[pdfsubject={Mathématiques},unicode]{hyperref}` works on my computer.

Comment: When I compile your example code using `\usepackage[pdfsubject={Mathématiques}]{hyperref}` I get the right accented Subject (Mathématiques) in the resulting pdf properties. Do you get something different?

Comment: How i can close the question?