# LuaLaTeX and hyperref ate my document (properties). How do I get them back?

Tags: hyperref, luatex, unicode

I use `hyperref` for a number of reasons, but among other things it sets up the document properties up well. As long as I compile with XeLaTeX that is. As soon as I compile with LuaLaTeX, everything is a jumble. There are many more fields with issues in my real project, but here is an MWE using just the title field:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{turkish}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{%
        pdftitle = {\@title}
    }
}{}
\makeatother
\title{RAB'BİN GÜNÜ}
\begin{document}
Title in document properties should match: RAB'BİN GÜNÜ 
\end{document}
```

Compile with `xelatex` gives me:

> **Title:** RAB’BİN GÜNÜ

But `lualatex` eats Unicode for lunch and has indigestion:

> **Title:** RAB'BÄ°N GÃœNÃœ

How do I get proper Unicode characters into the document property fields when compiling with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Christopher The document properties aren't typeset with a font. They are in the program chrome of whatever PDF reader you are using. And yes the default font typesets the characters fine in the document body. I use Libertine in my documents but I don't think it's relevant to this MWE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using non ASCII characters in author names and titles within hyperref pdfinfo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/using-non-ascii-characters-in-author-names-and-titles-within-hyperref-pdfinfo)

Comment: @MartinSchröder This is probably a duplicate but I'm concerned that the accepted (and indeed most of the) answers there are wrong and do _not_ work in the general case (I think they only worked for a limited non-ascii character subset but doesn't actually work for full Unicode). Perhaps that question should be closed as a duplicate of this one as the answer provided here is far more canonically the correct fix for this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The indigestion is avoided by passing the `unicode` option to `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{turkish}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{%
        pdftitle = {\@title}
    }
}{}
\makeatother
\title{RAB'BİN GÜNÜ}
\begin{document}
Title in document properties should match: RAB'BİN GÜNÜ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output of `pdfinfo -enc UTF-8 test.pdf` (only the relevant parts)

#### LuaLaTeX

```
Title:          RAB'BİN GÜNÜ
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       LuaTeX-0.79.1
CreationDate:   Tue Mar 24 12:01:09 2015
ModDate:        Tue Mar 24 12:01:09 2015
```

#### XeLaTeX

```
Title:          RAB'BİN GÜNÜ
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       xdvipdfmx (20140317)
CreationDate:   Tue Mar 24 11:58:05 2015
```

Comment: The clumsy `\AtBeginDocument` can be avoided here by the `hyperref` option `pdfusetitle`. Then `hyperref` catches `\title` and `\author` to use them for `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the behavior differs when LuaTeX or XeTeX is used, is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236863/incorrect-encoding-in-pdf-outlines/237277#237277). The XeTeX uses `xdvipdfmx` and this converter sets the UTF8 to UCS2 conversion automatically. On the other hand, when we are using direct pdfTeX primitives (like in LuaTeX) then the UTF8 to UCS2 conversion must be done at macro level. And the `hyperref` package does this when the mentioned `unicode` option is set.