# Incorrect encoding in PDF outlines

Tags: plain-tex, dvipdfmx

I'm trying to get encoding in PDF outlines right. The problem is that the letter in the outline must be `Ъ` - the same as on the page - but it is `Ú`.

`dvitype` shows this:

```
xxx 'pdf: outline 1 << /Title (?) /Dest [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>' non-ASCII character in xxx command!
```

Below is the example file (I know, it's somewhat lengthly, but I did my best to remove as much irrelevant parts from the original file as I could). Run with:

```
$ tex -ini -enc '\input plain \dump'  
$ tex -fmt plain example.tex  
$ dvipdfmx example.dvi
```

example.tex:

```
\font\tenbf=labx1000

\newtoks\gtitle % title of current major group

\newtoks\toksE \newtoks\toksF \newtoks\usersanitizer
\newif\iftokprocessed \newif\ifTnum \newif\ifinstr

\def\firstsecno#1.{\setbox0=\hbox{\toksA={#1.}\toksB={}%
    \maketoks}}
\def\addtokens#1#2{\edef\addtoks{\noexpand#1={\the#1#2}}\addtoks}
\def\poptoks#1#2|ENDTOKS|{\let\first=#1\toksD={#1}%
  \ifcat\noexpand\first0\countB=`#1\else\countB=0\fi\toksA={#2}}

\def\maketoksdone{\edef\st{\global\noexpand\toksA={\the\toksB}}\st}

\def\sanitizecommand#1#2{\addtokens\usersanitizer
       {\noexpand\dosanitizecommand\noexpand#1{#2}}}
\def\dosanitizecommand#1#2{\ifx\nxt#1\addF{#2}\fi}

\def\makeoutlinetoks{\Tnumfalse\afterassignment\makeolproctok\let\nxt= }
\def\makeolnexttok{\afterassignment\makeolproctok\let\nxt= }
\def\makeolgobbletok{\afterassignment\makeolnexttok\let\nxt= }
\def\addF#1{\addtokens\toksF{#1}\tokprocessedtrue}
% now comes a routine to "sanitize" section names, for pdf outlines
\def\makeolproctok{\tokprocessedfalse
  \let\next\makeolnexttok % default
  \ifx\nxt\outlinedone\let\next\outlinedone
  \else\ifx{\nxt \else\ifx}\nxt \Tnumfalse \instrfalse % skip braces
  \else\ifx$\nxt % or a $ sign
  \else\ifx^\nxt \addF^\else\ifx_\nxt \addF_% sanitize ^ and _
  \else\ifx\nxt\spacechar \addF\space
  \else\if\noexpand\nxt\relax % we have a control sequence; is it one we know?
    \ifx\nxt~\addF\space
    \else\ifx\nxt\onespace\addF\space
    \else\the\usersanitizer
    \iftokprocessed\else\makeolproctokctli
    \iftokprocessed\else\makeolproctokctlii
    \iftokprocessed\else\makeolproctokctliii % if not recognised, skip it
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
   \else  % we don't have a control sequence, it's an ordinary char
    \ifx/\nxt \addF{\string\/}% quote chars special to PDF with backslash
    \else\ifx(\nxt \addF{\string\(}\else\ifx)\nxt \addF{\string\)}%
    \else\ifx[\nxt \addF{\string\[}\else\ifx]\nxt \addF{\string\]}%
    \else\expandafter\makeolproctokchar\meaning\nxt
   \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \next
}
\def\makeolproctokchar#1 #2 #3{\addF{#3}}
\def\makeolproctokctli{%
  \ifx\nxt\CEE\addF{C}\let\next\makeolgobbletok % \CEE/
  \else\ifx\nxt\UNIX\addF{UNIX}\let\next\makeolgobbletok % \UNIX/
  \else\ifx\nxt\TEX\addF{TeX}\let\next\makeolgobbletok % \TEX/
  \else\ifx\nxt\TeX\addF{TeX}\else\ifx\nxt\LaTeX\addF{LaTeX}%
  \else\ifx\nxt\CPLUSPLUS\addF{C++}\let\next\makeolgobbletok % \CPLUSPLUS/
  \else\ifx\nxt\Cee\addF{C}%
  \else\ifx\nxt\PB \let\next\makeolgobbletok \tokprocessedtrue % \PB{...}
  \else\ifx\nxt\.\tokprocessedtrue\instrtrue % \.{...}
      % skip \|
  \else\ifx\nxt\\\ifinstr\addF{\bschar\bschar}\else\tokprocessedtrue\fi
  \else\ifx\nxt\&\ifinstr\addF&\else\tokprocessedtrue\fi
  \else\ifx\nxt\~\ifTnum\addF{0}\else\addF\tildechar\fi % 077->\T{\~77}
  \else\ifx\nxt\_\ifTnum\addF{E}\else\addF_\fi  % 0.1E5->\T{0.1\_5}
  \else\ifx\nxt\^\ifTnum\addF{0x}\else\addF^\fi  % 0x77 -> \T{\^77}
  \else\ifx\nxt\$\ifTnum\tokprocessedtrue\else\addF$\fi % \T{77\$L}
  \else\ifx\nxt\{\addF\lbchar       \else\ifx\nxt\}\addF\rbchar
  \else\ifx\nxt\ \addF\space        \else\ifx\nxt\#\addF{\string\#}%
  \else\ifx\nxt\PP\addF{++}\else\ifx\nxt\MM\addF{--}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}

\def\outlinedone{\edef\outlinest{\global\noexpand\toksE={\the\toksF}}%
  \outlinest\let\outlinedone=\relax}

\def\lapstar{\rlap{*}}
\def\stsec{\rightskip=0pt % get out of C mode (cf. \B)
  \sfcode`;=1500 \pretolerance 200 \hyphenpenalty 50 \exhyphenpenalty 50
  \noindent{\let\*=\lapstar\bf\secstar.\quad}%
  \smash{\raise\baselineskip\hbox to0pt{%
     \let\*=\empty\special{%
       pdf: dest (\romannumeral\secstar) [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ]}}}}
\let\startsection=\stsec

\def\MN#1{\par % common code for \M, \N
  {\xdef\secstar{#1}\let\*=\empty\xdef\secno{#1}}% remove \* from section name
  \ifx\secno\secstar\fi
  \mark{{{\tensy x}\secno}{1}{\the\gtitle}}}
\let\ZZ=\let % now you can \write the control sequence \ZZ

\let\page=\pagebody \raggedbottom
\def\startpdf{
    {\special{pdf: docview << /PageMode /UseOutlines >>}}}

\newwrite\cont
\output{\setbox0=\page % the first page is garbage
  \openout\cont=\jobname.toc
  \global\output{\shipout\vbox{
    \vbox to 9in{
    \hbox to 6.5in{\vbox to10pt{}}
    \vfill\page}}}}

\vbox to \vsize{} % the first \topmark won't be null

\def\makebookmarks{\let\ZZ=\writebookmarkline \readcontents\relax}
\def\expnumber#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax 0%
  \else \csname#1\endcsname \fi} % Petr Olsak's macros from texinfo.tex

\def\writebookmarkline#1#2#3#4#5{{%
  \let\(=\let \let\)=\let \let\[=\let \let\]=\let \let\/=\let
  \pdfoutline goto num #3 count -\expnumber{chunk#2.#3} {#5}}}

\def\main#1#2#3.{% beginning of starred section
  \toksF={}\makeoutlinetoks#3\outlinedone\outlinedone
  \gtitle={#3}\MN{#2}%
  \vfil\eject
  \def\stripprefix##1>{}\def\gtitletoks{#3}%
  \edef\gtitletoks{\expandafter\stripprefix\meaning\gtitletoks}%
  \edef\next{\write\cont{\ZZ{\gtitletoks}{#1}{\secno}% write to contents file
   {\noexpand\the\pageno}{\the\toksE}}}\next % \ZZ{title}{depth}{sec}{page}{ss}
  \special{pdf: outline #1 << /Title (\the\toksE) /Dest
    [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>}
  \startsection{\bf#3.\quad}\ignorespaces}

\mubytein=1 \mubyteout=2
\mubyte ^^da  ^^d0^^aa\endmubyte

\main{1}{1}Ъ.

\bye
```

**EDIT:**
To sum up the answers, these are my current settings (without intermediate packages):

```
\newbox\mybox
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\afterassignment\myboat\setbox\mybox=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\special{pdf:tounicode UTF8-UCS2}\unvbox\mybox}\oldshipout\box\mybox\global\let\shipout\oldshipout}
```

(idea from quire.tex)

Comment: If you use UTF-8, you will have a correct
outline encoding by using dvipdfmx
in the following way:

`\font\tenbf=labx1000`
`\special{pdf: tounicode UTF8-UCS2}`
`\special{pdf: outline 1 << /Title (Ъ) /Dest`
`[ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>}`
`Ъ.`
`\bye`

Comment: In the above example, the outline is right,
but the text is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @Akira: tounicode did not solve the problem ... until I did further investigation and discovered the \specialout register of encTeX. It must be set to 2. So, both tounicode and \specialout used together make it all work! Write it in the answer, please. Also, in your example you are missing this: \mubytein=1 \mubyteout=2 \specialout=2 \mubyte ^^da  ^^d0^^aa\endmubyte; and use \bf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 input encoding and encTeX is assumed:

```
\font\tenbf=labx1000
\mubytein=1 \mubyteout=2 \specialout=2 \mubyte ^^da ^^d0^^aa\endmubyte
\special{pdf: tounicode UTF8-UCS2}
\special{pdf: outline 1 << /Title (Ъ) /Dest
[ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>}
\bf Ъ.
\bye
```

In the case of your example, you are redefining

```
\output
```

Therefore please add the following two lines at the top of your example.tex:

```
\input atbegshi.sty
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\special{pdf: tounicode UTF8-UCS2}}
```

Here atbegshi.sty is a package by Heiko Oberdiek.

**EDIT:**
Instead of using atbegshi.sty, you may use a more straightforward way to add "tounicode" special:

```
...
dviasm -o example.dump example.dvi
perl -i -pe "s/(?<=\[page 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\])/\nxxx: 'pdf:tounicode UTF8-UCS2'/" example.dump
dviasm -o example.dvi example.dump
dvipdfmx example.dvi
```

Comment: There is one more problem: if \special{pdf: tounicode UTF8-UCS2} is placed before call to the macro in which "outline" special is used - "tounicode" special is not output to the dvi file. Why? ("tounicode" special will work only if it is placed just before "outline" special: take example.tex above, add \specialout=2, then add "tounicode" special to the **top** of the document and compile; then run "dvitype example.dvi")

Comment: @Igor: I added some lines in my answer.

Comment: This works. Neat.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is only two documented encodings for PDF strings (used in PDFoutlines, PDFinfo etc.): First one is default: PDFDocEncoding. It is one-byte encoding, but is is unusable in non-English and non west-European languages (like Czech). Second one: PDFunicode encoding. It is special two-byte encoding derived from UTF16 with starting prefix FEFF (hexa). Each PDF string must be prefixed by this prefix and encoded by UTF16 unless it is PDFDocEncoded string.

The `dvipdfmx` converter is able to add the mentioned prefix FEFF and to convert UTF8 to UTF16 in all PDF strings when `\special{pdf: tounicode UTF8-UCS2}` is set. The XeTeX uses `xdvipdfmx` converter in its backend and it activates this UTF8-UCS2 conversion automatically.

PdfTeX in dvi-mode can be set by the above mentioned setting. Then the `dvipdfmx` post-processor does the desired work.

But PdfTeX in PDF-mode outputs directly to the PDF strings (using `\pdfoutline` primitive for example) and we need to do the UTF8 to UTF16 conversion at macro level. The file `pdfuni.tex` solves this problem for Czech and Slovak alphabet. The `\pdfunidef\macro{text}` is defined here: the `text` is converted to UTF16 and saved to the `\macro`. Then the `\macro` can be used as an argument of `\pdfoutline` primitive. You can be inspired by the code from `pdfuni.tex` and you can implement similar macros for Cyrillic if you need to use pdftex in PDF mode.