# Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }

Tags: errors, hyperref, texlive, babel, compilation-error

This only throws the error when running it with TexLive 2017 on Debian 9. If I run the same example on Windows 10 with MikTex, everything works fine:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=brazil,english,spanish,french}{babel}
\documentclass[brazilian,brazil,10pt,a4paper,]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\autor}[1]{\author{#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirautor}{\theauthor}
\newcommand{\brazilword}[1]{\foreignlanguage{brazil}{#1}}

\autor{\brazilword{Your Name}}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={\imprimirautor},
}

\begin{document}
Hi.
\end{document}
```

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
! Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.14 }

? H
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Comment: Your example does not work fine with miktex: check the author in the pdf properties, you will see the word "brazil" there. Adding `\protect` helps, but in general it is not a good idea to add lots of complicated commands like `\foreignlanguage` to stuff that should end in the pdf booksmarks or info dictionary.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, MikTex should throw an error as TexLive does at least.

Comment: a current texlive doesn't give an error either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching for it, I could find these related questions:

1. [microtype expansion leads to error in pdfauthor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300893/microtype-expansion-leads-to-error-in-pdfauthor)
2. [XeLaTex + babel (\addto\extras{lang}) + hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478958/xelatex-babel-addto-extraslang-hyperref)

I tried both of these answers, but none of them worked.

After looking over the code, I found that adding `\protect` before the `\foreignlanguage` babel command, fixed it for TexLive 2017 and MikTeX. The only question is why it worked correctly before for MikTeX without "protection" while it throw errors for TexLive.

1. https://texfaq.org/FAQ-protect
2. [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect)
3. [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)